# Getting value from wordpress input with python selenium

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium

I got to take value from this input:

Image from wordpress:

[image]

and assign it into variable to use in further steps, but don't know how to extract this text to assign,
tried with getText:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@onclick,'this.select();')]").getText()
print(test)
```

but there is error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Do you have any idea how to get this 'playerid' value?

Answer (score 0):

To get text from the web element with Selenium in Python the method is `.text`, not `.getText()`.
`.getText()` is used in Java.
So your code should be

```
test=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@onclick,'this.select();')]").text
print(test)
```

**UPD**
It's not a text, it's a value.
Try this instead:

```
test=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@onclick,'this.select();')]").get_attribute("value")
print(test)
```

Comment: If I give .test then nothing is shown in the output, I tried to see what will come out without anything at the end:
test=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@onclick,'this.select();')]")
print(test)

and this is the result:
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ce8e81d38e8f2473de5d03f2d2dc8a94", element="eb43f664-41c8-412d-aef3-5009ea28e94c")>

Comment: OK, that means you do catch the web element itself, but not the text inside it.

Comment: Try adding a sleep before getting the element. Let me know if that helped. Just a `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: Tried with that, still nothing shows when there is .text at the end

Comment: Now I see. It's not a text, it's a value! See updated answer. Let me know if it works now

Comment: It works!!! thanks!! how can I reward your help here?